# Calling a void function?

Tags: c, function-pointers, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

I'm trying to write a program that can recognize a palindrome.

I've made a function for recognizing if it is a palindrome and used it in main successfully.

However, I also want to remove any spaces or numbers or special characters as those could interfere with recognizing it as one.

I've tried calling on it in main with `inputstring(isalphabet)` but it won't compile at all. Also tried changing isalphabet to char instead of void, and giving it `return inputstring` but it won't work. Any and all suggestions appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPalindrome(char inputString[]);

int main() {
    char inputString[100];   
    int ret;

    scanf("%s", inputString);
    
    ret = isPalindrome(inputString);

    printf("%d", ret);
}

int isPalindrome(char inputString[]) {
    int count = 0;
    int result;

    while (inputString[count] != '\0') {
        count++;
    }

    char stcp[100];
    int i = count, j = 0;

    while (i != 0) 
        stcp[j++] = inputString[--i];

    stcp[j] = 0;

    if (strcmp(inputString, stcp) == 0) {
        result = 1;
    }
    else {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;   
}

void isalphabet(char inputString[], char nystring[]) {
    int count, i, ny_i = 0;
    count = strlen(inputString);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (isalpha(inputString[i]) != 0) {
            nystring[ny_i] = inputString[i];
            ny_i++;
        }

        nystring[ny_i] = '\0';  
    }
}
```

Comment: If you ask questions about build errors, then please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question itself. Also please add a comment on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: #include <string.h>

Comment: *inputstring(isalphabet)* - did you literally call it like that? inputstring is a variable and isalphabet is a function, so it should be something like isalphabet(inputstring, nystring)

Comment: @notmenotyou Move this statement nystring[ny_i] = '\0'; outside the for loop.

Comment: Side note: you need to include header `<ctype.h>` to use `isalpha()` function; also, you need to put the prototype of `isalphabet()` (i.e.: `void isalphabet(char[], char[]);`) before `main()` as you did with `isPalindrome()`.

Comment: Instead of modifying and copying the string to a new string, it's probably easier to just use pointers, one at the start going forwards, one at the end going backwards, you can check `isalpha` and move them more if it's not, until the pointers collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the auxiliary array with the magic number 100

```
char stcp[100];
```

is a bad idea. The user can pass to the function a string of an arbitrary length that can be greater than 100.

It seems what you need is something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isPalindrome( const char *s, int cmp( int ) )
{
    int palindrome = 1;
    
    const char *p =  s + strlen( s );
    
    while ( palindrome && s < p )
    {
        if ( !cmp( ( unsigned char )*s ) )
        {
            ++s;
        }
        else if ( !cmp( ( unsigned char )*--p ) )
        {
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            palindrome = *s++ == *p;    
        }
    }
    
    return palindrome;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%d\n", isPalindrome( "1a12b123c1234b12345a123456", isalpha ) );
    printf( "%d\n", isPalindrome( "1a2bc3def2gh1i", isdigit ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
1
```